# where are windows7 and windows8 loader images stored?

Tags: windows-7, loading

I tried to find the loader images of windows7 and windows8. Could not find a thing. I want to reporduce those on preloaders.net project. The horizontal image was easy, but the circular one is pretty hard :).

Does anyone know where windows7 and windows8 store their loader images?

Thanks in advance